# How to simulate faulty disks in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: hard-drive, debugging

For debugging purposes, I'd like to simulate the following states regarding disk drives on my VM with Ubuntu 20:

1. disk is missing/offline
2. disk is faulty
3. disk is not responding

While I could quickly solve the first one but removing the disk from the VM setup, the second and third one are a bit harder to simulate.

I tried with the approach found [here](https://lxadm.com/using-fault-injection), but it seems that either there is some info missing here that additionally needs to be loaded/installed, or the procedure has changed since the date of writing.
When I try to do something like

`echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/make_it_fail`

I get:

`-bash: /sys/block/sdb/make_it_fail: Permission denied.`

Also, the folder /debug/make_fail_request is not created for me.
It seems like there needs to be done to get this working on a recent kernel.

My second try was with the package "fiu-utils", but I can't find any info about how to use if for drives.

Is there any working approach for Ubuntu 20?

Comment: #1 is trivial: Add a drive, create mount point, remove drive.

Comment: The link where you say you're following an approach is broken. Is it simply because you aren't a user with permissions to do it? Try sudo bash and then your echo command or something similar to echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block...

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Yes, I already solved that case (see my text).

Comment: @jtessier72: I did everything as root user, nonetheless the permission denied occurs.

Comment: Your link is still broken (links to https://lxadm.com/using-fault-injection/here - remove the here) , but the article I think you wanted to link to says: "You need fault injection and debugfs compiled in the kernel." Is this in place?

Comment: This might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361518/how-can-i-simulate-a-failed-disk-during-testing

Comment: @jtessier72 that's exactly the article where I found the link I posted above. I have no idea if Canocial added debugfs and fault injection support in their kernels. That's why I posted by question here :-)